# Lucene QueryParser

Tags: lucene

Does Lucene QueryParser.parse(string) still work?
If it is deprecated, what is the new syntax?

Query query = QueryParser.parse("Ophelia");

Thanks
Tatyana

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as correct

Answer (score 7):

Not sure of the exact API, but it's changed to an instance object. All QueryParsers are now instance objects.

```
var qp = new QueryParser(new StandardAnalyzer(),fields);
qp.Parse(inputString,fields);
```

Comment: Slightly different in Lucene-2.4.0
but works

QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("the default field for query terms", analyzer);
Query query = qp.parse("Ophelia");

Thanks, 
Tatyana

Answer (score 1):

version 5.0:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(fields, new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.parse(searchString);
```

This is the newest api!